# What are some good resources for GNU Make?

Tags: gnu-make

I have read about 1/3 of the GNU Make manual, do you guys know of any resources to really learn the Art of using Make.

Ideally, there might be some examples where two ways of doing something are possible, and the author explains which method he chose and why.

I am primarily using Make not to build C/C++ programs but to operate a processing pipeline for data analysis.

Comment: just asking so i can get a better idea for what kind of resource you are looking for.. why would you choose make to do something like that?

Comment: @marcelog: because it makes sense. I do it all the time. You build up you analysis step by step. Then if you find a bug in one of the earlier steps, make knows what to remake once you fix the botched recipe.

Answer (score 7):

[Managing Projects with GNU Make](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/index.csp), by Robert Mecklenburg, is the best I've come across. Plus, it's an O'Reilly [Open Book](http://oreilly.com/openbook/), so O'Reilly gives away free PDFs of it on their website. Read it linearly, and start from the beginning (even if you think you already know the basics of GNU Make).

Comment: i'm so confused.  why would o reilly let you save as pdf and have a buy this pdf link for 30 bucks on the side ?!?

Comment: Because many of the people who downloaded it for free at home then persuade their boss to spend on the non-free version. At some companies, paid is easier to argue than free. Plus it brings an enormous amount of goodwill.

Comment: http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp

Answer (score 5):

John Graham-Cumming has written a book called GNU Make Unleashed which looks promising, although I have not read it yet.  http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/gnu-make-unleashed/2937580 and http://jgc.org/

Comment: According to the blog at http://jgc.org: as of July 18, 2014, the self-published version of *GNU Make Unleashed* is no longer available BUT a new version is to be published by No Starch Press, release date not yet announced.

Comment: As of April 2015, this book was renamed to "The GNU Make Book".   (Not sure who's idea that was; this book covers advanced concepts and the new name does not reflect that.)  It is published by No Starch Press.   ISBN-13:  978-1593276492